# What is the complex logarithm of $(-1)^{k}$

Tags: complex-numbers

What is the complex logarithm of $(-1)^{k}$ where $k$ is a positive integer. Is it possible to express it in function of $k$.

Comment: Assuming the principal branch gives$$(1-(-1)^k)\frac{\pi}2 i$$

Comment: $\log$ is an analytic group isomorphism $\Bbb{C}^* \to \Bbb{C}/2i\pi \Bbb{Z}$ and $\log (-1)^k = i \pi k + 2i\pi \Bbb{Z}$

Comment: @reuns: Can you convert this into an answer.