# How one can find the positive integer $k$ in term of complex logarithm of $f(s)/f(3-s)$ if $f(3-s)$ is not zero.

Tags: complex-analysis, analytic-functions

Let us consider the non constant complex analytic function $f$ on all $ℂ$ verifying the functional equation:

$$f(s)=(-1)^{k}f(3-s)$$

for all complex number $s$ where $k$ is a fixed positive integer.

My **question** is: How one can find the positive integer $k$ in term of complex logarithm ([What is the complex logarithm of $(-1)^{k}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3307440/what-is-the-complex-logarithm-of-1k?noredirect=1&lq=1)) of $f(s)/f(3-s)$ if $f(3-s)$ is not zero.

Comment: You can't find $k$. You can only tell if it's even or odd.

Comment: @MattSamuel: But $k$ is unique and fixed

Comment: That doesn't matter, the information is lost. Just like if you know that $(-1)^k=1$, all that tells you is that $k$ is even. It doesn't tell you what $k$ is. Similarly, if you know that $x^2=1$, that doesn't tell you what $x$ is, only that $x=1$ or $x=-1$.

Comment: @MattSamuel: You say: *The logarithm is multivalued, and it will yield all of the odd or even integers if you try to solve for $k$, depending on whether k is even or odd*. Can you elaborate with this

Comment: I expanded my answer.

Comment: @MattSamuel: So, if one cannot know the parity of $k$, then the formula: $$k = 2m+\frac 1{i\pi}\log\frac{f(s)}{f(3-s)}$$ is a representation of $k$ in term of $s$ and $m$.

Comment: Yes, except that $m$ is an arbitrary integer, so it's a representation of either all odd integers or all even integers. It's really overkill to try to use the logarithm, you can reason directly that $k$ is even if $(-1)^k=1$ or odd if $(-1)^k=-1$.

Comment: @MattSamuel: Thank you very much for these clarifications.

Comment: Sure, no problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The positive integer $k$ is for the most part unrecoverable from the functional equation, because most of the information is gone after raising $-1$ to the power of $k$. Using the complex logarithm won't help; all you can tell is whether $k$ is even or odd. $k$ is even if
$$f(s)=f(3-s)$$
for some $s$ such that $f(s)\neq 0$, and odd if
$$f(s)=-f(3-s)$$
for some $s$ such that $f(s)\neq 0$.

The logarithm is multivalued, and it will yield all of the odd or even integers if you try to solve for $k$, depending on whether $k$ is even or odd.

In more detail, if you try to solve for $k$, you would write this as
$$e^{ki\pi} = \frac{f(s)}{f(3-s)}$$
so
$$k i\pi = 2m\pi i+\log\frac{f(s)}{f(3-s)}$$
as $m$ ranges over all integers. (If you know one logarithm, any other logarithm differs by an integer multiple of $2\pi i$).

Thus
$$k = 2m+\frac 1{i\pi}\log\frac{f(s)}{f(3-s)}$$
But here we know that if $k$ is even, then $(-1)^k=1$, so the principal logarithm of $\frac{f(s)}{f(3-s)}=0$, so $k=2m$ for some $m$. If $k$ is odd, then 
$$\frac{f(s)}{f(3-s)}=-1$$
so the principal logarithm is $i\pi$. Dividing by $i\pi$, we get that
$$k=2m+1$$
so $k$ can be any odd integer.